# Calendar and file manager partly in German

Tags: 14.04, language-support, calendar

Ubuntu 14.10, installed in English, with Belgian keyboard. No additional languages installed.

Everything is displayed in English as expected but some parts appear in German: the calendar and the dates in the file manager.

I have no idea how it got there, and how to get rid of it.

[image: File manager]
[image: Calendar]

Answer (score 5):

This is controlled by the [Regional Formats setting in Language Support](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-formats.html). Based on your time zone choice during installation, the installer 'guessed' that you prefer the Belgian conventions for time/date, currency, etc., so currently you probably have **Deutch (Belgien)** selected in the *Regional Formats* tab. Unfortunately (which is a [bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1072019)) it means that the weekday and month names are showed in German.

The simplest way to change it is to switch to some of the English options in *Regional Formats*. Often **English (Denmark)** is a suitable choice in Europe.

Another option is to edit your `~/.profile` file, and add the line

```
export LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8
```

That will fix the weekday and month names, without affecting things like currency and number formats.

Comment: I had already changed it to English, but nothing happened. Before I had the time to test your solution, I had installed the FR package. Then, the calendar was in French. So I uninstalled it, and after rebooting, the calendar and the file manager are now in English, as I wanted.

Comment: Note: "Deutsch" still appears in the "Language" tab, gryed out, so I can't get rid of it and whenever I try to access that tab, Ubuntu asks to install missing DE package. So wrong.

Comment: @youri: Changing the "Regional Formats" to English and relogin should do it. Only installing French (without changing any settings) should certainly not change anything. As regards missing language support packages: If I was you, I'd just install them. They won't hurt, and you won't be bothered by that prompt any more.

Comment: Almost 4 years later, this is Ubuntu 18.10. Same behavior, same incorrect guess by default. Same workaround.

Comment: ... and 7 years later as well

Comment: @WimOmbelets: Well, in 21.10 it ought to "guess" better if you install in English: Dutch instead of German. It's [bug #1907914](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1907914).